# How do I get Windows 10 Start Menu to tree all the folders?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

In previous versions of Windows (95-7), you could tree folders in the Start Menu.  In other words, you could have the Start Menu\Applications folder (now "All Apps") and have folder **work** and folder **games** in it. Games would have a shortcut to Minecraft, while work would have a shortcut to Word.
In previous versions, when selecting a folder, you could choose to pick a subfolder.
[image]
When I navigate to folder, I get 2 options. Go to games or work. Lovely.

Now that option is dust. There is no option to get something like that without software. It shows all of the applications A-Z and therefore will not do something like that. Only one folder is open/closeable but all the subfolders and their contents are just mashed up there. For example, if I had a folder named Folder: (like in the photo)

```
| -Folder **main folder**  
| --Work **subfolder**  
| }--Word **item**  
| --Games **subfolder**  
| }--Minecraft **item**
```

It would show like this:

```
** **F** **  
Folder >  
** **G** **
```

And once I click **Folder >** it displays:

```
** **F** **  
Folder >  
Minecraft  
Word    
** **G** **
```

So to make a long story short, how do I make Windows show the subfolders in Folder?

P.S.  If you can find a way to make Windows 10 short the applications by name like in Windows 8.1, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: There isn't a way.  How the Start Menu works was changed with the release of Windows 8.  Windows 10's Start Menu is the Start Screen turned into a workable Start Menu on non-touched devices.

Comment: @Ramhound That's not really true, the Windows 10 Start Menu was completely written from scratch.

Comment: @JosiahKeller - I never said it wasn't.  You are reading far to much into my comment.  The Windows 10 Start Menu is the evolution of the Start Screen for Windows 8.1.  Windows 8.1 was SUPPOSE to receive a similar update, Windows RT received that update, but Microsoft decided to give Windows 8.1 users a free upgrade to Windows 10 instead.  Some of these plans were leaked, some were semi-confirmed by presentations over the years, **there is no high context meaning to what I say.**

Comment: @Ramhound OK, when you talked about "How the Start Menu works" I assumed you were speaking from a technical point of view, not just talking about the UI.  Fair enough.

Comment: When I speak of from a technical point of view, I indicate that, I am a very low context communicator.

Comment: Since of the "No Software" aspect, this will be hard.

Comment: Do you mind changing it to the W7 start menu? the xp one made me cringe a little until a read the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The toolbars in the Windows Taskbar still have the expanding folder (legacy Start Menu) functionality.

**Add a toolbar to the Windows taskbar:**

1. Right-click on a blank area of the taskbar.
2. Select Toolbars, New Toolbar...
3. Navigate to the folder of your choice, such as:

   - C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
4. Click "Select Folder"

[image: Win10 - Expandable Folders]

Pro tip: You can still right-click on a menu item and click *Sort by name*.

Comment: Bonus tip: You can pin the metro apps to this panel.

Comment: Tried this, but only got a folder button on the toolbar, which on click opens the folder.

Comment: You have to make the toolbar small enough to get the » icon. Than when you click on the Icon you get the folder structure :-O.

Comment: This will only show a partial Start Menu, as `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` is the Start Menu directory for all users, whereas `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` is the user-specific Start Menu directory.

Answer (score 9):

The Windows 10 Start menu is beautiful, but frustrating for someone who is used to Windows 7.

Your options as I see them are :

1. Use the free [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) as replacement
   to the Windows 10 Start menu. Classic Shell has all the functionality
   of the Windows 7 Start menu (and even more).
2. [Pin the folder to the Taskbar](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-pin-any-folder-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-10/) by pinning it first to the Start menu,
   then pinning that to the taskbar, then unpin from the Start menu.

[image: classic shell]

Comment: Tried option 2. It only gives me a folder button that opens the folder on click.

Comment: Option 2 opens the folder, instead of cascade-opening folders on mouse hovering. Useful, but not the same.